# Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_result::$num_row

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I get error Message:Undefined property: `CI_DB_mysqli_result::$num_row`

my controller is

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Login_mod');
    }
    function login() {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $result = $this->Login_mod->validate($username,$password);
        if (!$result) {
            $msg = "<font color=red> Invalid Username or Password.</font></br>";
            $data['msg'] = $msg;
            $this->load->view('login/Login', $data);
        } else {
            $this->load->view('login/index');    
        }
    }
}
```

and my model is

```
<?php
class Login_mod extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function validate($username,$password) {
       // $username = $this->input->post('username');
      //  $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('pass', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        if ($query->num_row == 1) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

and my view is

```
<?php
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Account</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post"  method="post" name="login" action="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>Login/login">
                  <h2>Login Form</h2>
                  <div >
                      <label for="username" >Uername: </label>
                      <input style="margin-left:2px" type="text" value="" name="username" placeholder="User Name" id="username" required="" />
                </div>
                  </br>
                <div>
                    <label for="username" >password: </label>
                    <input type="password" value="" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required="" />
                </div>
                  </br>
                  <div>
                    <input type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Login">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_result::$num_row
>
> Filename: models/Login_mod.php
>
> Line Number: 27
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ov400\application\models\Login_mod.php
>   Line: 27
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ov400\application\controllers\Login.php
>   Line: 23
>   Function: validate
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ov400\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

Comment: it's `$query->num_rows()`

Comment: its not working

Comment: Whats the new error

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::num_row() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ov400\application\models\Login_mod.php on line 27

Comment: You didn't change it all. It's not `num_row()` it's `num_rows()`

Comment: its working but did not redirect to my index page

Answer (score 2):

Just a syntax error. The correct statement for the `if` clause in the model would be

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

And, if you'd like to compact this code to a one-liner using a ternary operator, you could use:

```
return ($query->num_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
```

the above would produce the same result, with a much cleaner code

Answer (score 1):

It's not `$query->num_row();` it's `$query->num_rows();`

Change your `validate` To this:

```
function validate($username,$password) {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('pass', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change Your Validate function**

```
 function validate($username,$password) {
 $this->db->where(['username'=> $username, 'pass'=> $password]);
 $query = $this->db->get('user');
 $num = $query->num_rows();
 if($num){
   return true;
 } else{
   return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query:

```
function validate($username,$password) {
 return $this->db->where('username', $username)->where('pass', $password)->get('user')->row_array();
}
```